# How can I make Gradle install targets replace a device's app on Lollipop devices like it does on previous versions?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop

Android's Gradle plugin has install targets built in so you can type the following to build and install your app to a connected device.

```
$ gradle installDebug
```

I've found, however, that my Lollipop device doesn't have the same replacement behavior that older releases of Android have.  Instead of replacing the installed version, it complains that the app is already installed, dumps a huge stack trace, and quits.

This behavior is mostly just annoying, but it makes it really hard to test stuff like database version upgrade code if you have to uninstall the older version first.

I can run `adb` like below with the magic `-r` flag to replace the APK as a workaround, but that's not very satisfying.

```
$ adb install -r build/outputs/apk/MyCoolApp-debug.apk
```

How can I make Gradle replace installed app with a fresh APK like it does with pre-Lollipop devices?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug in the plugin and has been [fixed in RC1](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).